# System.Web.Mvc.SelectList does not contain a definition for First

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'am assign a ViewBag variable with a SelectList and filling a DropDownList.
Ok this goes fine.

But I want take this opportunity to print the first one item of SelectList, but I'm faceded with this error.

> System.Web.Mvc.SelectList does not contain a definition for First

I'm trying this way

```
 @(ViewBag.WhateverVariable.First().Text)
```

There is a way to print the firt one item?,
Tks

Comment: Have you added the namespace for LINQ? `using System.Linq;` or `@using System.Linq`

Answer (score 4):

ViewBag is a dynamic dictionary. You should explicitly cast it to a `SelectList` first and then you can call the `First()` method

This should work

```
@((ViewBag.WhateverVariable as SelectList).First().Text)
```

Assuming your action method already set a `SelectList` to `ViewBag.WhateverVariable`

Keep in mind that `First` method will throw an `InvalidOperationException` exception when the source sequence is empty. So make sure to call the First method on an non empty collection.

Answer (score -3):

Try jQuery instead

For example if id of your dropdown/combo is combo1
then code would be :

```
var firstValue = $("#combo1").val($("#combo1 option:first").val());
<p id="firstVal"><p>
$("#firstval").html(firstValue);
```